# Student Seeking Programming Advice

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, xcode, machine-learning

I am a high school student, and I have just finished 4 free youtube courses on python, along with a "beginners guide to python" book, and I am a little lost. I understood the language quite well and enjoyed learning it. My question is: what do I have to learn in order for me to start designing and building things with python. Just to be clear, I am not talking about complicated things such as websites or machine learning applications. I am talking about simple games and apps so that I can form a better understanding of software development through practical experience. I honestly thought this is where the course and book would get me by now. I feel like my understanding of python is great (for a beginner). I understand all of the fundamental terms and definitions of the language, and I can answer questions other students may have about directories, methods, strings and so on without trouble. I just have no idea where to begin designing and building real things that can test my knowledge as a programmer.

I understand that I have a lot to learn. I just have no discernible vision as to how I can become better without practicing what I learn.

I am grateful for any advice you can provide on how I can resolve this issue, as well as any book recommendations or helpful links for learning resources.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of fun ways! Try some of Swagart's books (Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, etc). By all means try making a basic web application with Flask. Try making a game with Pygame (Al Swagart's pygame book is good for that). Try interfacing a database directly with sqlite3. The possibilities are endless. Don't stick to just raw python, the best way to get experience is to use external modules and apply your knowledge to them. If you need to write Python for a job they will want you to be using something or other to do something or other and the only way to be able to say "Oh yes I can learn this module you're using for webdev/game/anything" is to have experience learning new modules and use cases.

Comment: Thank's Theo, that is great advice. I will be sure to check out those books.